# App crash when open deep link url, while app is in inactive state in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using deep link to open my app from browser. When my app is in background state i can able to open the app and i can able to move to the respective screen based on the URL. But whenever i quit my app, and open the same URL, it is crashing. I have followed Deep link tutorial for creating all actions. And I am moving to another screen in "triggerImp" method. I have added my code below for navigation. Is it rite or do i need to add anything else. Please help me.

```
let vc = UIViewController()
(appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this exact code that you are using? Not sure the app will know what view controller to open if you set it to `UIViewController()`. Here is how I have it setup that works for both states, background and inactive (using Storyboards):

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: mainEntryStoryboardName, bundle: nil)
    let newHomeView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyView") as! MyViewController
    let navigation = MyNavigationController(rootViewController: newHomeView)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigation
    return true
}
```

hope this helps